# Gif not appearing in JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, gif

I'm currently developing a programme which utilises gifs to indicate loading on the programme. However, I can not get the gif to appear on the JLabel after trying several ideas. I have tested many things, including the following.

- Tried loading a png file instead of gif, this works, indicating no issue with the JLabel.
- Tried loading the gif into a JLabel in a completely separate programme, this also works, indicating no issue with the gif.
- Tried loading it in through URL AND through local resource, neither works.

The following snippet of code contains the main part of the declaration of the code. Any help is appreciated.

```
try {
        URL URL = new URL("https://i.imgur.com/sMD9yUD.gif");
        Icon Gif = new ImageIcon(URL);
        tempLoad1.setIcon(Gif);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    tempLoad1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    tempLoad1.setFont(new Font("Lato", Font.BOLD, 24));
    tempLoad1.setBounds(63, 111, 452, 71);
    contentPane.add(tempLoad1);
```

Note that tempLoad1 is declared at the start of the programme. I have also proved that this is not an issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: Q: What version of Java are you running?  Q: What OS are you running it on?

Comment: BTW - that code works just fine in an MCVE here. And it does that despite setting the bounds and the font (which is not used in any useful way). Post your own MCVE as an [edit] so we can see where it went wrong. (Voting to close.)

Comment: I'm not sure we actually need an MCVE: the problem is clear, and your code looks fine.  I suspect it's just a "bad" .gif.  SUGGESTION: get one of your .png files that "works", export it as a .gif, and see if the exported .gif displays.  ALSO: I *am* curious about your Java version and your OS (on the off chance it might be relevant).

Comment: *"I'm not sure we actually need an MCVE:"* Is that the royal 'we' @paulsm4? If not, don't speak for me. I'm **certain** the OP will not be getting my further attention until there is an MCVE in evidence.

Comment: "We" denotes collegiality, camaraderie.  Don't take offense ;)  And kudos to you for creating your own little test program.  Which, to my mind, verifies that the OP's code is probably OK, and it's instead the file that's suspect.

Comment: ` I have tested many things, including the following.` - so forget about the gif. First just display a label with text to see if the basic logic works. If it works then you know the problem is in how you read the gif. If it doesn't work then you know the problem is in the structure of your code. That is why you need to create the [mcve]. We have no idea what you are really doing.